# Connection between variance and mean square error

Tags: statistics

My textbook defines:

• The variance  $V(x) = \sum_{r=1}^{N} P_r (x_r - <x> )^2$, where < x > is the expected value and $P_r$ the probability that $x_r$ occurs.

• The mean square error as $s^2 = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} (x_i - <x> )^2$

Then it just continues to say $<s^2> = \frac{N-1}{N} V(x)$ . Could someone explain to me how we get to the last relation? I've already googled it, but many websites simply use both synonymously.